What to do about question posts requesting answers to multiple questions?
How do I write a good answer? advises avoid trying to answer questions which... request answers to multiple questions.
I left a comment to this effect under a question post from a new user.
It felt awkward not being able to point to some guideline directly addressing question posts.
What (beyond skip/ignore) should one do noticing a multiple question post, especially from a new user?

Vote to close the question as 'needs more focus', or flag the question for closure as 'needs improvement' >> 'needs more focus'.  The help text with that closure reason says:

The question must be edited to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer, and not ask multiple distinct questions at once.

Optionally, you can also leave a comment with a suggestion for how they can make their question suitable here.
See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417486/781723 for more details.
